# Is multiple array initialization on the same line the same as on separate lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3.x, can arrays be initialized on the same line?

I'm trying to be a "one-liner guy," but not certain of the subtleties between these two.

**Minimal, complete, verifiable example:**

Are these statements equivalent?

A:

```
def main():
    a = b = []
```

B:

```
def main():
    a = []
    b = []
```

Comment: Use `a, b = [], []`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two are not equivalent; the first one creates two references to the same list:

```py
>>> a = b = []
>>> a.append(1)
>>> b
[1]
```

The second creates two lists:

```py
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> a.append(1)
>>> b
[]
```

To create two lists on one line, you can do a parallel assignment:

```py
>>> a, b = [], []
>>> a.append(1)
>>> b
[]
```